# Numpy Matrix Subtraction Confusion

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have a question about the result of an operation I accidentally performed with two numpy matrices (and later fixed).

Let's say that I have a column vector, A = [1,2,3], and a row vector B = [1,1,1]. As far as I know there is no correct mathematical way to "subtract" these two vectors, i.e. this should be an undefined operation. And yet, when I do so, I get back:

```
>>> matrix([[0, 1, 2],
            [0, 1, 2],
            [0, 1, 2]])
```

I thought that this might be some sort of broadcasting operation, but this still troubles me a bit. Shouldn't numpy.matrix objects only contain mathematically valid matrix operations?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It would be interesting to know.

Comment: google "numpy broadcasting"

Comment: @user1149913 I believe the question isn't how broadcasting works, but rather, why is a row allowed to add/subtract with a column vector?  Also, remember that broadcasting rules are much different for the `np.matrix` than `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Poking around through the numpy code I could only find np.subtract for arrays, could it be possible that numpy treats matrices as arrays for subtraction?

Comment: @askewchan I never really use `np.matrix`, but from a quick test they broadcast just as 2D arrays. What do you mean by "broadcasting rules are much different"?

Comment: @jorgeca, mainly when matrix multiplication has a rule, then `np.matrix` will follow it but `np.array` won't.  For example, using the `A` and `B` from my answer, `A*B` gives an outer product (resulting in a 3x3 matrix) but `B*A` gives an inner product (resulting in a scalar).  If you use `np.asarray(A)*np.asarray(B)` and vice versa, you get the outer product in both cases, which is the standard numpy broadcasting rule: `(3,1)` and `(1,3)` yields `(3,3)`

Comment: @jorgeca, another example is that a matrix can operate only on a column vector, so if you have a 3x3 matrix `C` and a 3x3 array `c`, then `C*B` is illegal, since `B` is a row vector.  Whereas `c*b` is legal where `c,b = map(np.asarray,[C, B])`

Comment: @askewchan `matrix` subclasses `ndarray`, and they follow the exact same broadcasting rules. The major differences are in the `__getitem__` method, that ensures a 2D object is always kept, and in `__mul__` that calls `.dot` instead of `np.multiply`. [The source is pure Python](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L329) and easy to follow.

Comment: @askewchan I now see what you mean. Though, I think that happens because `np.matrix` multiplication behaves as linear algebra multiplication, not because of broadcasting. In fact, `np.broadcast(A,B).shape == np.broadcast(B,A).shape`.

Comment: @jorgeca Yes, that's correct, I had misunderstood but Jaime's explanation is the best.

Comment: All fine and good, but this is not a mathematically valid statement, and hence should not be an allowed property of np.matrix (even though it inherits from numpy.ndarray). Multiplication of a vector and its dual is allowed in various ways (i.e. - broadcasting is an outer product). Subtraction and addition of these things should have no broadcasting happening under the hood whatsoever (even if the objects are identical in shape/dimension). Maybe I'm wrong, but broadcasting is a useful programming tool and is only really mathematically defined when you'd like to perform an outer product.

Comment: Using `np.matrix` is discouraged in part because of this kind of inconsistent behaviour. If you had been using 1D `ndarray` instead you wouldn't have accidentally got a 2D array. Broadcasting is a well defined operation for `np.ndarray` and the same rules apply to its `matrix` subclass even if it's not what you'd expect from a "mathematical matrix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A and B are being broadcasted together:

```
A = np.matrix([[1],[2],[3]])
#a 3x1 vector
#1
#2
#3

B = np.matrix([[1,1,1]])
#a 1x3 vector
#1 1 1

A-B
#a 3x3 vector
#0 0 0
#1 1 1
#2 2 2
```

A gets broadcasted along its size 1 dimension(columns) into

```
#1 1 1
#2 2 2
#3 3 3
```

B get broadcasted along its size 1 dimension(rows) into

```
#1 1 1
#1 1 1
#1 1 1
```

Then A-B is computed as usual for two 3x3 matrices.

If you want to know why it does this instead of reporting an error it's because np.matrix inherits from np.array.  np.matrix overrides multiplication, but not addition and subtraction, so it uses the operations based on the np.array, which broadcasts when the dimensions allow it.

Comment: But you have to be careful about who is using this. Mathematicians and physicists will not necessarily know this (even though a quick google of it could tell you) and will assume that this should return an error when it clearly doesn't. In my opinion, np.matrix should override for addition and subtraction as well. This is a math library we're talking about here.

Comment: I agree astromax.  When working on matrix objects I think it would be better to throw an error or exception by default instead of performing an unexpected operation.  Matlab gets this right

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really explain the rationale, because I often use `np.matrix` instead of `np.array` to prevent this sort of thing.  Thanks to @Jaime's link in the comments above, it's clear that `np.matrix` is simply a subclass from `np.ndarray` with redefined infix operations where there is an appropriate answer from linear algebra.  Where there isn't, it falls back on the rules from `np.ndarray` with `ndim = 2`.

It seems that **addition follows the matrix multiplication rules** for which elements from `A` are paired with which elements from `B`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: A = np.matrix([1,2,3]).T
In [3]: B = np.matrix([1,1,1])

In [4]: A
Out[4]: 
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])

In [5]: B
Out[5]: matrix([[1, 1, 1]])

In [6]: A+B
Out[6]: 
matrix([[2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]])

In [7]: A*B
Out[7]: 
matrix([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]])
```

This is the same behavior you get with `np.array`:

```
In [9]: a = np.arange(3)[...,None]

In [10]: b = np.arange(3)

In [11]: a
Out[11]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [12]: b
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [13]: a+b
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```