# Why is my gradient descent algorithm not working correctly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to mimic the gradient descent algorithm for linear regression from Andrew NG's Machine learning course to Python, but for some reason my implementation is not working correctly.

**Here's my implementation in Octave, it works correctly:**

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters


    prediction = X*theta;
    margin_error = prediction - y;

    gradient = 1/m * (alpha * (X' * margin_error));
    theta = theta - gradient;

    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

However, when I translate this to Python for some reason it is not giving me accurate results. The cost seems to be going up rather than descending.

**Here's my implementation in Python:**

```
def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, iters):
    m = len(y)

    J_history = np.matrix(np.zeros((iters,1)))

    for i in range(iters):
        prediction = x*theta.T
        margin_error = prediction - y

        gradient = 1/m * (alpha * (x.T * margin_error))
        theta = theta - gradient

        J_history[i] = computeCost(x,y,theta)

    return theta,J_history
```

My code is compiling and there isn't anything wrong. Please note this is theta:

```
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))
```

**Alpha and iters is set to this:**

```
alpha = 0.01
iters = 1000
```

When I run it, `opt_theta, cost = gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, iters)` and print out opt_theta, I get this:

```
matrix([[  2.36890383e+16,  -1.40798902e+16],
        [  2.47503758e+17,  -2.36890383e+16]])
```

when I should get this:

```
matrix([[-3.24140214, 1.1272942 ]])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

**Cost function**

```
def computeCost(x, y, theta):
#   Get length of data set
    m = len(y)

    # We get theta transpose because we are working with a numpy array [0,0] for example
    prediction = x * theta.T

    J = 1/(2*m) * np.sum(np.power((prediction - y), 2))

    return J
```

Comment: I see you are using `.T` as "prime". correct? If so then why in the Octane code are you not using theta prime for prediction but in the python code you are using theta prime? I don't know if this will solve your problem but good luck.

Comment: @gabeio In my Python code I am passing in an array and not a vector. In the Octave code theta is already a vector, but in Python it is not so I have to make it a vector

Comment: Can you show the computecost function in python.

Comment: @RohithRNair Yes, I just updated my question with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look there:

```
>>> A = np.matrix([3,3,3])
>>> B = np.matrix([[1,1,1], [2,2,2]])
>>> A-B
matrix([[2, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 1]])
```

Matrices are broadcasted together.

["it's because np.matrix inherits from np.array. np.matrix overrides multiplication, but not addition and subtraction"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797686/8730789)

In yours situation theta(1x2) subtract gradient(2x1) and in result you have got 2x2. Try to transpose gradient before subtracting.

```
theta = theta - gradient.T
```